# How to get get_instance in abstract class in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

There are three classes:

**Standard controller class:**

```
class LoaderContent extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct(){
        $obj = new SearchNew();
      }
}


abstract class Search
{
// Get here access to get_instance
}


class SearchNew extends Search
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct($type);
    }
}
```

How to get access to a Codeigniter instance in an abstract class?

Comment: abstract class Search extends CI_Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Codeigniter, get_instance() is a globally available function that returns the Controller super-object which contains all the currently loaded classes (it returns the Controller class instance).
First, assign the CodeIgniter object to a variable:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

Once you've assigned the object to a variable, you'll use that variable instead of $this:

```
$CI =& get_instance(); 
$CI->load->helper('url'); 
$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->config->item('base_url');
```

etc.

Note: You'll notice that the above get_instance() function is being passed by reference:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```